# How to test if distributions from two groups of replicates are different

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I know that the question I am asking has been stated before, but so far I have not found a suitable answer in any of these threads. As I have a very specific use case in mind, maybe someone this might make it easier to suggest an appropriate answer.

**Background:** I am a biologist researching disease models in mice, so the wording is associated with that.

**Data:**

- I have two groups of animals. For $A$ a certain gene, is normal i.e. *wild type*, and for $B$ the gene is defective i.e. *knock-out*. All the animals are related and other differences should be minimal. I am interested in the question if the genetic defect has an impact on a specific phenotypic measurement: Axon diameter.
- I analyzed multiple animals per group (n=5 per group)
- In each animal, I measured around 500-2000 axon diameters in a specific location.
- So I have 2x5 continuous empirical distributions of these diameters $A_{1-5}$ and $B_{1-5}$.

**Question:**

- Is there a difference in the shape of the distributions between $A_{1-5}$ and $B_{1-5}$.
- I am not interested in mere differences in population mean, as the genetic defects usually only affect certain bins of the distribution and resulting mean changes are small and difficult to detect. However, when looking at the distributions plotted as histograms, differences are usually visually apparent in one part of the distribution.

So far I have been using the KS test for all samples of the individual replicates for each group mixed together. In my opinion, this does not accurately reflect the structure of the samples. I am hoping that something that uses the information about the replicates might increase the power of the test while being more accurate.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to CV.  How is this a discrete distribution? Aren't diameters continuous? 

Also, can you be more specific about what you mean by "different" shape?

Comment: Thanks! yes you are right, probably a misunderstanding of the terminology on my end. Diameters are continuous of course.

Comment: Depending on the knocked-out gene, samples usually have fewer lower-diameter axons or fewer higher-diameter axons. Sometimes this reduces the number of total axons, i.e. the corresponding bins are simply lost. In other cases, the overall number stays the same, but the distributions are shifted. I was referring to shape, as the difference in mean is sometimes quite small, but when you directly overlay the histograms, you can often clearly see the differences visually.

Comment: @sparsepix .... if "discrete distribution" is not a correct description, why does the question still say that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, updated description accordingly.

Comment: This sounds like a conditional KS test, kind of like extending ANOVA to ANCOVA by considering a covariate (the individual animal in this case). I confess that I’ve never seen such a generalization of the KS test.

Comment: There is a 90ies econ paper on a generalization to conditional KS test, but I couldn’t find an implementation in R so far

Comment: @sparsepix Could you please post a reference for that paper? Even if there is not an R implementation, I would be interested in its derivation. There also might be an implementation in another software that can be ported to R.

Comment: Hi, gladly: https://doi.org/10.2307/2171880

Comment: I am not sufficiently versed in the maths of statistics myself to judge if this is exactly what you were referring to, I was just trying to see if anything comes up using the terminology you suggested.